# Process "/bin/sh -e /proc/self/fd/9" - what starts it and why?

Tags: kubuntu, upstart, process, autostart, plex

I have a process `/bin/sh -e /proc/self/fd/9` that runs on my system. `sh -e /path/to/file` in dash (which `sh` is symlinked to on my Kubuntu 14.10) just tests for existence of a file. In `/proc/self/fs` I have files 1, 2, 3, 4 but no 9. From googling it seems it might be to do with upstart?

So what process is starting this and/or why? Thanks.

Edit - pstree output:

```
k1210:~$ pstree -ps 1890
init(1)───sh(1890)───start_pms(1902)───Plex Media Serv(1905)─┬─python(1926)─┬─{python}
```

[...]

Edit 2 - start_pms shell script:

https://gist.github.com/pbhj/777a191a55491bf432eb

Edit 3 - init.d file for plex:

https://gist.github.com/pbhj/bfb4a2303e727124efbc

Sufficient info has been provided however for my curiousity as to which service/app was causing the process to be created, ie "it's part of plex". Thanks.

Comment: Get the PID of that process, then run `pstree -ps PID`, and add the output to the question.

Comment: Additionally, `test -e` tests for existence. `sh -e` is used to exit if an unchecked command returns a non-zero exit code. What this command does is read in commands from this file descriptor, and `/proc/self` refers to the current command, so when you do check `/proc/self/fd`, you're not checking the file descriptors of that process.

Comment: Thanks @muru - pstree shows this process as parent to `start_pms` which itself is responsible for starting the Plex Media Server. Not sure how I've survived this long without knowing pstree! Solved.

Comment: You may want to adjust the Upstart job for Plex to `exec` start_pms so that this extraneous shell process does not hang around.

Comment: @CameronNemo - I don't know enough about why this is started, nor indeed how. Have added gist link for start_pms (a shell script).

Comment: Check the `/etc/init` folder for any `.conf` files related to Plex. To start or stop Plex you might use a command like `sudo service plex-blah start` or `sudo service plex-blah stop`, in which case, look for a file named `plex-blah.conf`. Please update your post with the contents of that file.